# Use specific font for emojis only in Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, emoji

Is it possible to use a specific font for emojis only in Android? Looking for the possibility not to use the standard emojis provided by the OS. Or do I have to replace the standard font (Roboto) in the entire app or apply font-family on certain views?
I assume there is nothing like a "font queue" in Android?

Comment: There are many ways. For example use special typeface for EditText / ViewText by method setTypeface() etc

Comment: My question is if there is a simple way to replace "Noto Color Emoji" which I assume is the default font used for emojis in Android, without replacing Roboto (Which does not contain emojis?)